# Rails 4: Ajax 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to upload a data_uri image from my [webcam](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) by ajax with rails uising [this gem](https://github.com/timsly/carrierwave-data-uri)

For that I have a custom function on my **PicturesController.rb:**

```
  def upload_image
    data_uri = params[:data_uri]  
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    @picture.user_id = current_user.id 
    if data_uri
      @picture.photo = data_uri
    end
      @picture.save
  end
```

and the **javascript** on my page:

```
function save_photo() {
      Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/pictures/upload',
          async: true,
          data: { data_uri: data_uri }
        })
        .done(function () {
          console.log(data_uri);
        });

        // shut down camera, stop capturing
        Webcam.reset();
      } );
    }
```

I'm also use the gem [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to solve cross domain problems.

My **route.rb**

```
  resources :pictures do
    collection do
      post 'upload', :action => :upload_image
    end 
  end
```

But when I call the ajax function I getting the **400 (Bad Request)**

The console show the error:

**ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: picture:**

Has anyone had this problem before?

Thanks!

Comment: my first thought is do you need to tell the controller what format to return and does it need a file named upload_image.js.erb in the view folder? I typically use the rails built in method so not familiar with if you need to do either of those.

Comment: I just find this error on the rails console:     ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: picture:

Comment: could you post the params being past once you submit the ajax request?